# Stopping jQuery toggle function running on child elements

Tags: jquery, inheritance

On a website design I've got a recent news section which shows thumbnails + title of recent new posts. In total there are 12 news stories (3 rows of 4) which are displayed. Via CSS the "Recent News" div has a height set which shows only the first row by default. This is the jQuery which creates the toggle height

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#recentnews").toggle(function(){
        // Show two rows (8)
        $(this).animate({height:387},200);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
        return false;
    }
    ,function(){
        // Show three rows (12)
        $(this).animate({height:565},200);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
        return false;
    },function(){
        // Show one row (4)
        $(this).animate({height:211},200);
    });
});
```

This works fine, but the problem I've got is anything within the recent news div will run this toggle function. This is a problem as any of the recent news stories now can't be physically clicked to go to the story.

Is there a way to remove the toggle inheritance? Or am I using toggle in the wrong way?

Comment: you can use e.stopImmediatePropagation() on a click event, that will stop the click event from propagating through the divs (which might trigger other toggles depending on your code)

Comment: You legend! I added this before my toggle statements

$("#recentnews ul li a").click(function(event){
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

And it works great! If you write an answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Glad it worked out! I wrote an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` on a click event, that will stop the click event from propagating through the divs (which might trigger other toggles depending on your code).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to e.stopImmediatePropagation()! for reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/